# player на kivy/kivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, mediaplayer

Как сделать `"сегментный" player для видео(как на сайтах, сегменты подгружаются с БД)` на kivyMD?
Я не прошу код.
Я прошу дать описание как это сделать, чтобы потом я сам пошёл гуглить.
**Но, если вам не трудно прикрепить код, будет просто отлично!**
С kivy/kivyMD знаком довольно неплохо, поэтому, не надо включать в описание довольно очевидные вещи.
Знаком с виджетом VideoPlayer, но как его использовать с сегментами - не знаю.
Есть англоязычная версия вопроса, может, там описание будет попонятнее.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61803374/videoplayer-kivymd-python
Спасибо.

Comment: Что такое  сегментный плеер?

Comment: Плеер для видео как на сайтах. У меня есть видео разбитое на части - сегменты, я хочу сделать так, чтобы по очереди эти сегменты подгружались и воспроизводились.

Comment: На сайтах, обычно, приходит index.m3u в котором перечислены сегменты в нужном порядке. Возможно вам нужно именно это?

Comment: Как вариант использовать c python-ffmpeg-video-streaming или Python m3u8 parser.

Comment: @Tihon, у меня есть файл в котором записаны всё сегменты в нужном порядке. Далее, у меня в kivy приложении есть виджет VideoPlayer, мне нужно сделать плеер как на сайтах, чтобы сегменты погружались по очереди и и.д Если вы не знакомы с kivy, боюсь вы мне не поможете. Мне нужно встроить сегментный player в приложение

Comment: @uberchel, можно по подробнее? Если с помощью python-ffmpeg-video-streaming или  Python m3u8 parser я смогу встроить player или видео в kivy приложение, то это - мой вариант. Хоть вопрос был другой, но всё же